# DELETE statement with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, **Table_A (DB1)** and **Table_A (DB2)** in ***different databases*** (*DB1* and *DB2* respectively). In these two tables, *price* and *quantity* may differ (or may be the same) even if the *item_id* and *store* is the same.

```
                **Table_A (DB1)**   

**item_id**  **store**   **price**   **quantity** 
     1           A            1           1
     2           B            2           4
     1           C            1           1
     3           A            1           1
     3           C            2           1
     2           A            2           3
     3           B            2           2



                 **Table_A (DB2)**  

**item_id**  **store**   **price**   **quantity**            
     1           B            1           2
     2           A            2           3
```

Now I want to delete all such records from **Table_A (DB1)** for which the *item_id* is not present in *Table_A (DB2)* (remember, these tables may have different price and quantity for a given combination of *item_id* and *store*). The table I intend to get is as shown below (*Table_A (DB1)-updated*):

```
                **Table_A (DB1)-updated**   

**item_id**  **store**   **price**   **quantity** 
     3           A            1           1
     3           C            2           1
     3           B            2           2
```

To select such *item_id*s from *Table_A (DB1)*  for which the *item_id* is absent in *Table_A (DB2)*, I am using the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_id FROM DB1.Table_A
WHERE item_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT item_id FROM DB2.Table_A);
```

The above query gives me list of *item_id* absent in Table_A (DB2) (but present in Table_A (DB1)).

Now I wish to delete all the records from Table_A (DB1) with *item_id*s that we obtained in above step. I also want to do the same in just one go. I am trying to run the following query but it returns an error.

```
DELETE FROM DB1.Table_A WHERE item_id IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT item_id FROM DB1.Table_A
WHERE item_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT item_id FROM DB2.Table_A));
```

The error I get is:

Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'Table_A' for update in FROM clause

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: check it here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Comment: While Bill's comment does answer your question w.r.t to the problem you faced, your query is doing unnecessary distincts.  Try using a simple query like this  and have an index on item_id column                                                                                                                                      DELETE FROM DB1.Table_A
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                                  FROM DB2.Table_B
                              WHERE Table_B.item_ID = Table_A.Item_ID)